# Arrange N unit squares in form of a grid such that number of rectangle is maximum?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, maxima-minima, rectangles

You are given N square tiles of dimension 1×1. You have to arrange them in form of a grid such that total number of rectangle (of all possible dimensions) is maximum.
Hollows within the grid are not allowed. The grid should be a complete rectangle. Only extra tiles after a complete rectangle can be placed on the side to form additonal rectangles.

**Example**: When N=8

**27  Rectangles**

```
 _ _ 
|_|_|_
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
```

**30  Rectangles**

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

**36  Rectangles**

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Hence, 36 rectangles is desirable.
Can anyone help me in formulating the formula for the same in terms of N?

I received this problem from a friend who in turn might have recieved it from assignment or a maths contest.
My first thought of solving this problem is for each integer value of row calculate maximum possible columns and then put the remaining tiles along the smaller side(so that those tiles can form maximum combination with bigger side) . This way we might have to try out rows from 1 to $\sqrt N$ . Now I hear there can be better approach than this. Let me know if you can think of any.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, the question is not *motivated*. In discrete mathematics, often a small detail may distinguish an easy problem from an impossible-to-solve one. Is this something you just thought of (in which case it may become a challenge for people to try to do), or is it from a programming challenge (where you can use brute force to solve it), or is it from a book (which?) or is it from a math contest (which? Has it finished? If not, we won't want to help just yet.)

Comment: Also, do you care about *rectangles made by sides of the squares* or about *rectangles filled by squares*? (Imagine a $3\times 3$ grid with the middle square taken out. This is again a way to tile $8$ squares. How many rectangles are there? $12$ or $36$?)

Comment: @DavidK Sorry I misunderstood your question, hollows are not allowed.  The grid should be complete . only extra ones can be placed on the side to form additonal rectangles.

Comment: A version of the "put the remaining tiles along the smaller side" taken to its extreme is to just have a single row of squares. One row of $8$ squares (a $1\times8$ grid) forms $36$ rectangles, which is better than the $2\times4$ grid. But of course all this shows is that one row is the best of three examples for $8$ squares. Something to think about is whether there is an example with $N$ squares that is better than a $1\times N$ grid.

Comment: correct. updated with that example. I didn't know if N x 1 is the answer or not which is why that example didn't stike me while writing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let us require that the grid be a full rectangle for simplicity.  Then given $N$ we can factor it as $a \times b$ with $a\le b$ and make such a grid.  We select two rows and two columns with replacement to get a rectangle.  There are $\frac 12a(a+1)$ ways to select the rows and $\frac 12b(b+1)$ ways to select the columns for $\frac 14ab(a+1)(b+1)$.  Assuming $N$ is a square, the limiting cases are $a=1,b=N$ and $a=b=\sqrt N$.  In the first case we get $\frac 12N(N+1)$ rectangles.  In the second we get $\frac 14N(\sqrt N+1)^2=\frac 14N^2+\frac 12N^{3/2}+\frac 14N$ rectangles.  If $N=4$ the $2 \times 2$ has $9$ rectangles while the $1 \times 4$ has $10$. The $1 \times N$ grid dominates.

The way to make this rigorous is to show that decreasing $a$ always increases the number of rectangles, showing that $a=1$ is optimal.